# After update from GitHub "We updated our RSA SSH host key" all my build's are failing in CircleCI

Tags: github, devops, pipeline, circleci, circleci-workflows

GitHub posted this [article](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/) today 24.03.2023 but based on this can someone help me with CircleCI, I think because of this all my builds are failing and I get this message when CircleCI tried to install dependencies:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The RSA host key for github.com has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address 140.82.114.3
is unknown. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "/home/circleci/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "github.com"
RSA host key for github.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: See: https://circleci.com/docs/github-integration/#establish-the-authenticity-of-an-ssh-host

Answer (score 3):

on 23-03-2023 GitHub update RSA keys , Follow below command update.

https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

steps for mac users

1. `ssh-keygen -R github.com`
2. Install JQ (optional: if you get jq not found than run this cmd) `brew install jq`
3. `curl -L https://api.github.com/meta | jq -r '.ssh_keys | .[]' | sed -e 's/^/github.com /' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 2):

Just run command:

```
ssh-keyscan -H github.com > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

my solution is by upgrading git-shallow-clone to latest version @2.5.0

Comment: Guys this actually works! Simple - probably refresh key in background. Shall we accept this solution?